# Dynamic ng-model name for UI sortable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ngmodel

I have two nested ng-repeat to list dishes of different categories, and I'm using UI Sortable to be able to sort those lists. The ng-model name for the latter is dynamic (matches the value of the category listed) and I simply don't know how to set that name and make it work.

I used $eval() to set that dynamic name in the ng-repeat and works fine, but tried the same for the model and it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thank you!

"categories" object:

[image]

All categories have items, for example first one "breakfast" (matching the "value" of the category) will look like this:

[image]

What I've tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in categories">   

    <div class="row">                               
            <div class="category-title">{{cat.name}}</div>
    </div>                            

     <div ui-sortable ng-model="cat.value">
<!-- <div ui-sortable ng-model="$eval(cat.value)"> -->
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,dish) in $eval(cat.value)">                
            <div class="dish-title">{{dish.name}}</div>              
        </div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example in JSFiddle or plunker?

Comment: Will `$eval(cat.value)` refer to an object? As you are using `(key, dish)`. Doesn't ui-sortable require an array?

Comment: Hi @tasseKATT I've updated my post so it's clearer to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<div ui-sortable ng-model="this[cat.value]">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,dish) in this[cat.value]">
    <div class="dish-title">{{dish.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```